# How to dynamically set a window's focusable property on Linux?

Tags: linux, electron

I have experienced a problem with `BrowserWindow.setFocusable ()` when used on Linux. I expect it to alter the window's `focusable` property but it does not. Is there any way to achieve this on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

The [official Electron documentation on this function](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetfocusablefocusable-macos-windows) explicitly states that this is not supported on Linux, only on MacOS and Windows. Thus, no, you cannot alter the focusing behaviour of an Electron app on Linux at runtime.